# Does Event Handling not work the way I thought or am I missing another detail?

Tags: c#, event-handling, monogame

I'm having trouble getting my Player object to continue doing what it was doing after invoking an event.

I am working on a little platformer using Monogame, and have run into a bit of an issue. The way I'm handling collisions is I have a container that holds the game area's solid collision masks (simple Rectangles) and my Player has a mask. When the player moves, it invokes an event proposing its new position. The GameController takes that event and uses it to compare the player's proposed position and collision mask against the solids, and if it finds any collisions, passes those collisions into the player, where the player processes them to adjust its Proposed Position and then finally moves.

The problem is it seems as though once the event is invoked, the GameController does its thing and I never return to the code in my Player until I purposely try to move.  I'm relatively new to events and event handling, and it sounded like this was a good way to have the GameController and Player communicate, but is it interrupting the Player's code flow and never returning to it? I guess my thought process was that the game would process its event handling method, then return to where we left off in the Player's code, but that either is not how it works, or I'm missing a step.

**ActorPlayer Properties**
Creates the Event to be fired off when the Player indicates any movement.

```cs
public delegate void PlayerMoveEventHandler(object source, EventArgs e);
public event PlayerMoveEventHandler PlayerMoved;
```

**GameController Initialize**
Subscribes to the Player's PlayerMoved event, assigning the OnPlayerMove method to it (see that method below)

```cs
Player = new ActorPlayer(0, PlayerIndex.One, new Vector2(112, 104));
Player.PlayerMoved += OnPlayerMove;
```

**ActorPlayer Update**
At Line 23, the ActorPlayer calls the OnPlayerMove() method, which fires off the event for any subscribers

```cs
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    float deltaTime = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    ProcessInput(deltaTime);

    if(IsGrounded == false)
    {
        // Add Gravity
        FallVector = FallVector + new Vector2(0, Global.GRAVITY_RATE * deltaTime);

        if (FallVector.Y > 4f)
        {
            FallVector = new Vector2(0, 6f);
        }

        Velocity = Velocity + FallVector;
    }

    if (Velocity != new Vector2(0))
    {
        ProposedPosition = Position + Velocity;
        CreateProposalMask(16, 24);
        OnPlayerMoved();

        if (IsColliding == true)
        {
            for (int i = Collisions.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                HandleCollision(Collisions.ElementAt(i));
                Collisions.RemoveAt(i);
            }

            IsColliding = false;
        }

        Position = ProposedPosition;
        Velocity = new Vector2(0);
        CreateCollisionMask(16, 24);
    }
}
```

**ActorPlayer OnPlayerMoved**
Triggers the event if any subscribers are listening

```cs
protected virtual void OnPlayerMoved()
{
    PlayerMoved?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

**GameController OnPlayerMove**
The method GameController runs if my Player's PlayerMoved event is triggered

```cs
public void OnPlayerMove(object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Check for Collisions against ProposedPosition on Player
            foreach (EntityCollisionSolid solid in MapContainer.CollisionSolids)
            {
                if (Player.CollisionMask.Intersects(solid.CollisionMask) == true)
                {
                    Rectangle _collision = Rectangle.Intersect(Player.CollisionMask, solid.CollisionMask);
                    Player.AddCollision(_collision);
                }
            }

            if(Player.IsGrounded == true)
            {
                Rectangle belowPlayerMask = new Rectangle(Player.CollisionMask.X, Player.CollisionMask.Bottom, Player.CollisionMask.Width, 1);

                foreach (EntityCollisionSolid solid in MapContainer.CollisionSolids)
                {
                    if (belowPlayerMask.Intersects(solid.CollisionMask) == true)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }

                Player.PlayerFalling();
            }
        }
```

My assumption is that it would flow like this:
Player Checks for Input / Gravity. Creates a Velocity.
Player Combines their current Position with Velocity to create a movement Proposal.
If any Velocity exists, Player invokes its OnPlayerMoved event.
GameController is subscribed to that event, so it jumps in and uses the ProposalPosition to check for collisions that will occur if the player moves.
If the GameController finds any collisions, it adds Collision Rectangles to the Player's list to adjust their Proposal and avoid going into the wall/floor.
The Player continues after this, checking if any Collisions have been added to its list. If so, it adjusts its ProposalPosition.
Finally, the Position is updated to ProposalPosition.

What is actually happening is that when the OnPlayerMoved event triggers, the GameController does exactly as it was asked, but then nothing happens until I provide input again.  It is as though it leaves the player's Update method during the event call and never returns to it. That may be how Events are supposed to work and I'm just unaware.

**EDIT** Thanks for everyone's suggestions! I'm still new to this, so I apologize for the mess of code shared before :) I have updated the code snippets above to properly show the delegate and EventHandler creation, subscription, triggering, and handling, as suggested below! The setup I have above works for what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: _"That may be how Events are supposed to work and I'm just unaware."_ -- no, that's not how events work. The code you posted seems reasonable. However, the devil's in the details and likely there's something about the flow of execution not apparent from the fractional code you've shared. After invoking the event handler delegates via the `PlayerMoved?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);` method call, execution should continue normally, i.e. just as for any method call. I'm not familiar with Monogame specifically, but if control isn't returning as expected, I would suspect an exception ...

Comment: ... being thrown during the handling of the event, and the Monogame framework catching and handling that exception. This is what Unity3d does, something I'm more familiar with. If Monogame has a debug console where you can see runtime error messages, there's probably something there telling you what's wrong. If you're able to step through the code in a debugger, then do that and find the spot where the code "leaves the rails", so to speak (i.e. the next executed statement isn't what you expected...the point at which that happened will be where an exception was thrown).

Comment: Additionally: while not strictly wrong, one should always be very careful about responding to events by calling back into the sender of the event. Depending on the implementation, this can trigger additional events, causing some re-entrant behavior that the object isn't prepared to handle, or it might just wind up modifying something that's not in the right state to be modified. Again, the code you posted seems fine to me, even in that respect, but because you're in the context of a broader framework, and haven't shared a good [mcve], it's always possible there are hidden flaws.

Comment: Just knowing that it should return to the code as normal is a relief. I can scour from that point and find where my hang-up is. I've not seen any errors come up in the debugs of my runs, but I'll do some additional testing :) You've been immensely helpful!  I will report back with what I find!

Comment: Could you please provide the event assignment code and the event firing code.  Without this information, the question and your answer can not help anyone with a similar problem in the future.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, For the most part, the MonoGame framework is not event driven(as exposed) nor multi-threaded(Depends on the platform, but synchronization is maintained internally through locking).  The only MonoGame event that I have ever handled is `OnClientSizeChanged()`. MonoGame like XNA before it, does not catch most runtime errors(if it does, they are expressed through the `innerException` property of the caught and rethrown error).  XNA was designed as a C# implementation of DirectX, with supporting classes and the minimal `Game` class implementation to get started...

Comment: @PeterDuniho...MonoGame continued that tradition and expanded it to multiple platforms. It is not a game engine like Unity3D. IMO, events are not often implemented since: 1. Call order among subscribers is not fixed. 2. There is a runtime performance penalty due to null and bounds checks on the delegates provided.  The traditional pattern for Input handling is to poll the states(Keyboard, Mouse, GamePad, Touch) in `Game1.Update()`(The main game loop) and pass the values to the affected objects or, as I prefer, to implement a `static` InputManager class and request the values from each class.

Comment: @Strom Definitely! I've updated the original question with code snippets that should properly show the steps I took to resolve the issue :) Thanks for the additional information, by the way! I never thought to use a static class to read input states. I may integrate that, moving forward!

Comment: I find it advantageous in `InputManager` to define things like a fire action`public static bool Fire` and set it true for left mouse button or spacebar or right trigger or touch on a given rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, so I had my GameController subscribed to the event, but the GameController hadn't been finished on my end, so portions of my collision detection were still being handled in my Main() loop. Moving those over to my GameController and adjusting the Update methods fixed the issue. Many thanks to Peter for helping me understand Events much better! I'd have just given up on the idea altogether soon without his input :)